# Work stealing and Kernel-level thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, kernel, work-stealing

Work stealing is a common strategy for User-level Thread. Each process has a work queue for taking work, and will steal from others' queue when they are out of work to do.

Is there any kernel that implements such strategy for Kernel-level thread ? If not, what is the reason ?

I believe in Linux there is a notion of thread-migration in kernel-level thread, which migrates thread from high-load processor to low-load processor but that seems like a different algorithm. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What??  CPU cores can only execute one thread at a time.  The core is either 100% flat-out running the thread, or it is not, (neglecting handling interrupts).

Comment: @MartinJames: What is your point ? I say nothing about how many thread a core can execute.

Answer (score 2):

The work stealing scheduler is a parallel computation scheduler. It is usually on user level libraries (like Intel tbb: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) or even languages like Cilk (https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cilk-plus)

Kernel-level threads are scheduled by the operating system, and as so the scheduling techniques are quite different. For instance, in work-stealing scheduler, one of the objectives is to limit memory usage (as proven in the original paper: http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/steal.pdf) and to achieve that the threads are stored in a deque. However, in operating system's schedulers the main objective is to be fair between the users, give each process/kernel thread a fair amount of time to run (as max-min fairness states: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-min_fairness), etc. Operating System's schedulers even use different priorities among kernel threads/processes (please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_feedback_queue). For that reason, work stealing implementations are made in user-level, since their objective is to schedule user-level threads inside a process and not kernel-threads.

Comment: if I wasn't clear please tell me in order to edit my answer :)